# 2KM distance FM Transmitter?

Tags: audio, radio

I'm looking to do something like a Drive-in cinema but for music play. Is it possible? Is there a FM Transmitter device I can use that can support about 2-3KM coverage? Can it operate at least 12 hours non-stop? has Good audio quality?

I wanna do a PORTABLE setup on an open field plug it to mixer and cars should receive audio(music) from their FM tuner?

Is this possible?

I have found a few long range FM transmitters via Google but I wanna know if this is possible and practical before buying the devices. Any recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly possible to broadcast over any distance of your choosing, it's just a matter of what equipment you need and what licenses you will require.  When conditions are right, it's even possible to bounce a signal around the world at the proper frequencies.

For FM, you will need a transmitter with sufficient power, the necessary local clearances to operate it (at a 2km range, there is a good chance it will be considered a radio station) and the necessary legal permission to play the audio you want to play.

Unfortunately, the majority of this (all the legal aspects) depend entirely on where you want to transmit from and we aren't likely to be able to help you much with that.  As for signal power, this also depends on the equipment being used to receive and the terrain from which you are broadcasting, so you would really need to experiment a bit in order to figure out what works for your environment.